# Predict Entropy based on the Balanced Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

You cannot use values but must determine from looking
The equation I have trouble with is as follows:

> $$\ce{2Na(s) + 2H2O(l) -> 2NaOH(aq) + H2}$$

According to my teacher the entropy is positive. I also got the entropy to be positive, but now that I think of it, the moles is decreasing and one is becoming aqueous. So does turning into a gas trump everything?

What if NaOH was solid? Would it mean still that the entropy would be positive?

Also finally according to the textbook the entropy values is as follows:

> $$\ce{s<l<<g}$$

But where would the **(aq)** be?

Answer (score 4):

Aqueous salts will always have less order than solid salts. There is **much** less order when ions are floating around in solution than when they are in their rigid lattice structures. This is what I think you are failing to consider. The reaction is not so much:

$$\ce{2Na_{(s)} + 2H2O_{(l)} -> 2NaOH_{(aq)} + H2_{(g)}}$$

But really:

$$\ce{2Na_{(s)} + 2H2O_{(l)} -> 2Na^{+}_{(aq)} +2OH^{-}_{(aq)} + H2_{(g)}}$$

What results from the reaction of 2 atoms of a very structured metal and 2 molecules of liquid water, is 4 aqueous ions that are free to move within the solution, and one molecule of gas. Not only are there now more species present, but they are also in a relatively more free states than before.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was thinking about that dissociation.